# Cheese won't start: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

Tags: 12.04, webcam, cheese

Cheese (photobooth) used to open just fine on my iMac 12,2 running Ubuntu 12.04 however it has stopped opening from either the launcher or terminal. I thought it might be due to running WMII but I logged into unity and ran it from the launcher and terminal and still no luck. The terminal output is:

```
Gtk-Message: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

(cheese:21704): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:21704): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:21704): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:21704): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:21704): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkGrid to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:21704): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

(cheese:21704): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_no_show_all: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(cheese:21704): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show_all: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
libv4l2: error getting pixformat: Invalid argument

** (cheese:21704): CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_uuid: assertion `CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

This leads me to think the last line is what is causing it to not start up but I have no clue. I have tried removing with "sudo apt-get --purge remove cheese" and then reinstalling but it still crashes on start-up. The webcam still works because when I use 'guvcview' the webcam shows up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like there's a bug open on Launchpad about this, with no solution as of yet.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/930128

I saw another thread about this on the Ubuntu forums, but their solution was hardly a "solution":
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969336

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally I encounter the same problem. It is usually after weeks of running my desktop. It is definitely a bug, however after I replug my USB camera, everything is fine. Reboot also works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I haven't run Ubuntu for a year or so now (I now run Arch), but can say that I now use a tool `guvcview` for webcam use.